# How to create a jar without manifest file and main class?

Tags: java

I have around 40 to 50 class files, and none have a main method or a manifest file. Now I have to create a `JAR` file from these files. How do I do this?

Comment: yes zip it and change extension thats it :)

Comment: a .jar file is nothing but a zip file with a different extension. a manifest and main class are only needed if you want to run your jar as executable, but a jar can just as well be used as a library of classes, used after importing in a project.

Answer (score 14):

```
$ jar cf myjarfile.jar *.class
```

will create a jar file with a manifest containing info about the jar file, but *without* specifying a main class. A main class is not mandatory (e.g. if you're simply creating a library and not an application jar)

Or (perhaps more what you want), the `M` flag

```
$ jar cMf myjarfile.jar *.class
```

will create the jar file *without* the manifest.

Answer (score -1):

Try this (Linux).

```
zip -r jar.zip classPathDirHere (just create zip)
mv jar.zip jar.jar (just rename)
```